# scanf_s проблемы с "прозрачными символами" (пробелы, табуляции и т.п.)

Tags: c

Доброго времени суток! И сразу к сути, если вводить ТОЛЬКО "прозрачные символы"  (пробелы, табуляции и т.п.) программа не считает это ошибкой, как заставить её выводить printf("Error!"); при отсутствии символов?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


int main() {

    char s[50];
    scanf_s("%s", s, _countof(s));
    if (strlen(s) > 2) printf("Word: %s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что есть "прозрачные символы"? Желательно в виде более употребимого термина или сразу в кодах таблицы ASCII.

Comment: Вопрос дополнил, для ясности.

Comment: Ничего не ясно. Это каким это образом вы в этот `scanf` вводите "только прозрачные символы"? Это невозможно, ибо `%s` не читает "прозрачные символы" в принципе. О чем тогда речь?

Comment: ввожу n пробелов, жму enter, смотрю результат, а результата нет, программа считает что ничего не произошло, это и нужно исправить, вы хотите сказать что если я заменю `%s` на `%i` к примеру, то функция `scanf_s` все увидит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `isspace()` проверяет что символ является white-space символом. Остается в цикле посчитать число таких символов во введенной строке и сравнить с общей длиной строки.

Comment: Я бы добавил, что функция содержится в `ctype.h`.